# Переделать ссылки вокруг картинки в список

Tags: html, css

Пробую делать одно и тоже несколькими вариантами в качестве практики. Помогите пожауйста вместо того варианта как сделано переделать все списком  ul и использовать :nth-child. Не используя классы для элементов li

Как я понимаю чтобы сделать это списком придется попариться с позиционированием.
Наверное тогда и картинку нужно фоном вставлять, чтобы не мешала список позиционировать. И нужно ли иконки этих ссылок тоже делать через css вместе img..

И еще я видимо неправильно посчитала ширину элементов и отступов.
В данном варианте центральная картинка перекрывает 3 пикселя у кнопок слева. Но получается как-то так, что она лежит чуть ниже, чем верхний элемент в наведенном состоянии. И поэтому кусочек верхнего элемента выглядывает из-за картинки

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.services{
  width: 980px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*padding: .5rem 1rem;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5b667a;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 36px 15px;
  height: 56px;
  width: 235px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn img {
  display: none;
}

.btn:hover img{
  display: block;
  margin: 12px auto;
}

.btn:hover{
  height: 128px;
  background: #6884ad;
  margin: 0 13px;
}

.otolaryngologist:hover{
  background: #ffcc29;
}

.row {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.right {
  width: 25%;
  float: right;
}

.center {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.center img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/pediatria.png" alt=""/>Педіатрія</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/therapy.png" alt=""/>Терапія</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="#" class="btn otolaryngologist"><img src="images/otolaryngologist.png" alt=""/>Отоларинголог</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/cosmetology.png" alt=""/>Косметологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/mamology.png" alt=""/>Мамологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/dietology.png" alt=""/>Дієтологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/urology.png" alt=""/>Урологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/surgery.png" alt=""/>Хірургія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/usd.png" alt=""/>Узд</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/laboratory.png" alt=""/>Лабораторія</a>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8zsJ.png" alt=""/>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/neurology.png" alt=""/>Неврологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/dermatology.png" alt=""/>Дерматологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/cardiology.png" alt=""/>Кардіологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/traumatology.png" alt=""/>Травматологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/gynecology.png" alt=""/>Гінекологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/proctology.png" alt=""/>Проктологія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/manual_therapy.png" alt=""/>Мануальна терапія</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/physiotherapy.png" alt=""/>Фізіотерапія</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/massage.png" alt=""/>Масаж</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на [ru.so]. Здесь принято помогать, а не делать работу за других. Покажите пожалуйста как Вы пробовали сделать новую верстку самостоятельно и укажите, что у Вас не получилось сделать.

Comment: @Alex с новой версией я пока что мучаюсь, а вот на счет пару пикселей которые видны при наведении на верхний левый элемент не подскажите? возможно там лишнее margin: 0 13px; но без этого все ломается

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы отступы слева и справа от картинки были одинаковые и чтобы верхние кнопки не выходили за границу картинки?

Comment: @Alex да, но сейчас левые и правые кнопки немного со сдвигом вправо

Comment: более простой вариант, чтобы слева и справа расстояние до картинки было одинаковым, Вам нужно увеличить ширину `.left` и `.right` и уменьшить `.center`. Но и кнопки вверху нужно будет уменьшить. [Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/o40dsnf0/).

Comment: и уточните пожалуйста, что Вы хотите заменить на списки - блоки `left`, `right`, `center` ? ссылки-кнопки хотите поместить в `li` ?

Comment: @Alex спасибо, изменила .left, .right, .center и margin и теперь все ровненько

Comment: @Alex в li поместить хочу кнопки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.services {
  width: 980px;
}
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /*padding: .5rem 1rem;*/
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  background: #5b667a;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 36px 15px;
  height: 56px;
  width: 179px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul:nth-child(2)>li:nth-child(1) .btn,
ul:nth-child(2)>li:nth-child(3) .btn{
  width:238px;
}
.btn img {
  display: none;
}
.btn:hover img {
  display: block;
  margin: 12px auto;
}
.btn:hover {
  height: 128px;
  background: #6884ad;
  margin: 0 13px;
}
.otolaryngologist:hover {
  background: #ffcc29;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
}
ul:nth-child(1)>li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul:nth-child(2)>li {
  float: left;
}
ul:nth-child(2)>li:nth-child(1) {
  width: 30%;
}
ul:nth-child(2)>li:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30%;
}
ul:nth-child(2)>li:nth-child(2) {
  width: 40%;
}
ul:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2) img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="services">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/pediatria.png" alt=""/>Педіатрія</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/therapy.png" alt=""/>Терапія</a></li>
 </ul>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn otolaryngologist"><img src="images/otolaryngologist.png" alt=""/>Отоларинголог</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/cosmetology.png" alt=""/>Косметологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/mamology.png" alt=""/>Мамологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/dietology.png" alt=""/>Дієтологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/urology.png" alt=""/>Урологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/surgery.png" alt=""/>Хірургія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/usd.png" alt=""/>Узд</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/laboratory.png" alt=""/>Лабораторія</a><li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8zsJ.png" alt=""/>
  </li>
  <li>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/neurology.png" alt=""/>Неврологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/dermatology.png" alt=""/>Дерматологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/cardiology.png" alt=""/>Кардіологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/traumatology.png" alt=""/>Травматологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/gynecology.png" alt=""/>Гінекологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/proctology.png" alt=""/>Проктологія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/manual_therapy.png" alt=""/>Мануальна терапія</a><li>
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/physiotherapy.png" alt=""/>Фізіотерапія</a><li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>  
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#" class="btn"><img src="images/massage.png" alt=""/>Масаж</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**UPD:**

> И еще я видимо неправильно посчитала ширину элементов и отступов. В
>   данном варианте центральная картинка перекрывает 3 пикселя у кнопок
>   слева.

Проблема возникает из-за неправильных размеров блоков. Для решения проблемы  ширина левого и правого блока увеличена, центральной части с картинкой уменьшена. Кроме этого, чтобы верхние кнопки не выходили за границу картинки, их ширина уменьшена до 179px.

Comment: спасибо вам большое) вернула верхним кнопкам прежний размер и вроде бы ничего за границу не выходит

Comment: @amaymon перепроверьте пожалуйста, сейчас верхние кнопки [не выходят за границу картинки](https://jsfiddle.net/dtoLnok8/). А если им вернуть прежний размер, то верхние кнопки [будут выходит за границу изображения](https://jsfiddle.net/dtoLnok8/1/).